# Applied CSS Triangle with Pseudo

Tags: css, icons, pseudo-element

I've managed to create a reload icon in pure css, but is uses a character that may break on some systems.  I know that one can create a [triangle in css](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), and that it can be [applied to pseudo elements](http://nicolasgallagher.com/an-introduction-to-css-pseudo-element-hacks/), but I have not been able to replicate the results for my reload icon.

Fiddle with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/codemastercode/xas5w/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
.reload.b::before {
    content:'';
    top: -4px;
    left: 3px;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid grey;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xas5w/2/

Comment: Perfect.  I tried something similar, but could see no change.  Thanks!